# Rewriting a Binomial expansion and expanding the rewritten version after making a convenience substitution to get a totally different answer

Tags: taylor-expansion, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I know that if I have a function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1}$$ that if I perform a binomial expansion on I get the  result $$f(x)\approx -1 -x -x^2-x^3-x^4 ...$$

However if I rewrite the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1} = \frac{1}{x(1-\frac{1}{x})} = \bigg[\big(1-\frac{1}{x}\big)\big(x\big) \bigg]^{-1}$$

Then we make the expansion of $\bigg[\big(1-\frac{1}{x}\big)\big(x\big) \bigg]^{-1}$ by using the subsitution $\frac{1}{x} = z$

We get $$(1-z)^{-1} = 1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4... = 1 + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3}+ \frac{1}{x^4}...$$
so that
$$x^{-1}(1-z)^{-1} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{1}{x^4}+ \frac{1}{x^5}...$$

This is completely different result!
Why is this the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expansion of $\frac 1 {x-1}$ you are using is valid only for $|x|<1$. When you change $x$ to $\frac 1 x$ and use the expansion you are assumung that $|x|>1$. Since there is no number with $|x|<1$ and $|x| >1$ you cannot use both of them for the same $x$.

Comment: Ahh so this stems from the general idea if you have an expansion $(1+ax)^n$ then its only valid for $|ax|<1$ right?

Comment: @PhysicsStudent Yes, that is right.

Comment: Suppose I also had a function $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)(z-2)}$ then if I want to expand such a function in the annulus $1 < |z| <2$ as well as for the region $|z| >2$, what sort of transformation should I make and how would I justify it?. I am aware that for such a function to expand in the disk $|z| <1$ its just a regular Taylor expansion.

Comment: Would it be writing $z-1 = z(1-\frac{1}{z})$ which implies $|\frac{1}{z}| <1$ and then leaving $(z-2)^-1$ unchanged since that is $-2^{-1}(1-\frac{z}{2})^{-1}$ which implies $|\frac{z}{2}| <1$

Comment: @PhysicsStudent Write it as $\frac 1 {z-2}-\frac 1 {z-1}$ and expand the two terms separetely. For the second term use expansion of $\frac 1 {1-\frac1 z}$

Comment: Thanks I think I understand what Is required